# Does "Each product is defined into final detail" have a meaning?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I was asked to proof-read an english text. The sentence "Each product is defined into final detail" caught my eyes, as I do not know if it is valid. I believe the client wants to say "Each product is defined down to the last detail."

Now I am not sure. Is the first version in any way correct or is it just plain wrong?

Comment: I agree the client is looking for "last detail", or wants to say "in ***fine*** detail".

Comment: An alternative possibility is "The final details of each product are defined". But without any linguistic or explanatory context, it's impossible for me to be sure. "Each product is defined into final detail" is not idiomatic English. Your query demonstrates the validity of the general principle that it is inadvisable to proofread text written in, or to translate into, a language that one does not speak like a native.

Comment: There was no real context, it was supposed to be displayed over a movie of the products (car parts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar looks correct to me, but without further context the meaning is indeed garbled. I can't parse what the sentence means, especially because I don't know what this product is. A physical product is not "defined": it's made, constructed, pieced together, processed, but definitely not "defined", at least not into a physical item.

The only meaning I could guess from that sentence is that "This is a finished product based on the final blueprint that we made", but like I said, without context it may be wrong

But for proof-reading-wise to me it looks correct, it's just meaningless

Comment: A manufactured physical product can be defined in the sense that the concept for it can be worked out and shaped, or its details can be designed. But certainly, in a movie subtitle 'defined' is too vague and imprecise unless the accompanying photography makes it obvious which meaning is intended.

Comment: @ErikKowal I meant that defining something does not create it, defining something simply conceptualizes it